# How to add a value to redirection

Tags: php, .htaccess, backend

I have a .htaccess problem.

I want to add a value to redirection, like:

```
domain.com/$1
```

to

```
domain.com/$1 + 1
```

so, when client address will be:

```
domain.com/1
```

server look for:

domain.com/0

It possible? I Can't find any guide about this.

Comment: you want domain.com/1 redirect to domain.com/0?

Comment: Seems to me like you could easily accomplish this with a standard catch-all `.htaccess` rewrite and then use a Router of some type to do this redirection for you.